# regex unicode multiline problem in Python

Tags: python, regex, unicode

I have some strings containing Unicode characters like bellow:

```
رده سنی مجاز : 
 10.2-15.3
 8.71-9.13
 25.08 - 31.2

زده های سنی غیرمجاز:
 16.5-18.4
 9.15 - 10.02
 20.02-21.30
```

I want to match the first number ranges like bellow:

```
10.2-15.3
8.71-9.13
25.08-31.2
```

and I'm using the following code:

```
print(re.findall('رده سنی مجاز :.*(.*\d+.\d+-\d+.\d+.*)', string, re.DOTALL))
```

but it returns:

```
['25.08-31.2']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest extracting all strings after the fixed text till a blank line, and then split the extracted part into separate lines:

```py
import re
 
p = r"رده سنی مجاز :\s*\n(.+(?:\n.+)*)"
text = "رده سنی مجاز : \n 10.2-15.3\n 8.71-9.13\n 25.08 - 31.2\n\nزده های سنی غیرمجاز:\n 16.5-18.4\n 9.15 - 10.02\n 20.02-21.30"
m = re.search(p, text)
if m:
    print([x.strip() for x in m.group(1).splitlines()])

# => ['10.2-15.3', '8.71-9.13', '25.08 - 31.2']
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/A1mRxp) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wz721Y/1).

*Details*:

- `رده سنی مجاز :` - a fixed string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\n` - a newline
- `(.+(?:\n.+)*)` - one or more non-empty lines captured into Group 1.